# Divide symbols in 2d array into 2 groups

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have the following problem. I have a `N*M 2d-array`, filled with `*` and `o`. Now I want to make a second array of the same size to mark all of the `*` as `1` or `2`, so basically putting them into `2` groups, so that no `1's` or `2's` are adjacent. Also if a `*` has no other `*` as neighbor mark him as `3`, for example:
`* o * o`
`o o * *`
`o * * *`
`* * o o`

becomes this:
`3 0 1 0`
`0 0 2 1`
`0 2 1 2`
`2 1 0 0`

I'm trying to just loop through all cells and when I find a `*` i put a `1` and it's neighbors as `2`, and so on. It starts with a `1` and then if there are many neighbors it works well, but if it meets another `*` that doesn't have a marked neighbor yet i don't know how to mark it, so i just put a `1` there. But it can collide with the rest, for example(let's visualize and put the numbers into the original one):
`o o 1 2`
`* * 2 o`
`o o * o`
Now my code would put a `1` as the T[1][0] star, following the right would become `2` and this is incorrect then. I don't know how to determine whether to put a `1` or `2` in such a situation. I've tried to put more neighbors below at the same time but the problem is always the same.

Comment: Minesweeper huh?  A floodfill type algorithm might do you better.  Or scan for a *, then count mines in adjacent sqaures and fill that in.  The second is how I would do it.

Comment: I don't think it's minesweeper at all.  The 1 and 2 doesn't sound to have any semantics, only that no two 1's or 2's are adjacent.  Replace 1 and 2 with X and Y and it's the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by filling the output array with 1's and 2's in a checkerboard fashion:

```
1 2 1 2
2 1 2 1
1 2 1 2
2 1 2 1
```

Then put 0's and 3's where needed. To do this, look at each element of the input array. If the element is a `o`, put a `0` at the same position in the output array. If the element is a `*`, check the four neighbors. If none are `*`, then put a `3` at that position in the output array.

```
3 0 1 0
0 0 2 1
0 2 1 2
2 1 0 0
```

You can actually do the whole process in one pass. If an element of the output array isn't supposed to be a `0` or a `3`, then you can choose between `1` and `2` as follows: if the row index plus the column index is an even number, then put a `1` in the output array, otherwise put a `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty well identified the problem: your given algorithm is fatally flawed.

You have to continue marking a contiguous group of stars, alternating `1` and `2` labels, until you run out of neighbors.  This is not a simple `for row ... for col` data structure: it's a lattice graph.

Start with your copy of the graph.

Find any `*`.  If it has neighbors, put them on the "two_do" list and mark the original location with a `1`.  If it has no neighbors, mark it with a `3`.

For each node on the "two_do" list ...
Mark the node with a `2`.
Add all of its neighbors to the "one_do" list.

Continue alternating between the "two_do" and "one_do" lists until you have no more neighbors that need marking.

Go back and find another un-numbered `*`.  If there aren't any left, you're done.

Using your given grid, (0,0) in the upper-left and (0, 3) in the upper-right:

```
* o * o
o o * *
o * * *
* * o o
```

In the first stage, we simply identify (0,0) as a `*` with no neighbors:

```
3 o * o
o o * *
o * * *
* * o o
```

Next, we find the `*` at (0,2).  Mark that with a `1`, and put the only neighbor on the "two_do" list:

```
3 o 1 o      (1, 2)
o o * *
o * * *
* * o o
```

Now, go through the list and mark those items (only 1) with `2`, putting their (its) open neighbors on the "one_do" list.

```
  grid       two_do   one_do
3 o 1 o      (done)   (1, 3)
o o 2 *               (2, 2)
o * * *
* * o o
```

Next, go through the "one_do" list, open neighbors going onto the "two_do_ list:

```
  grid       two_do   one_do
3 o 1 o      (2, 3)   (done)
o o 2 1               (2, 2)
o * * *
* * o o

  grid       two_do   one_do
3 o 1 o      (2, 3)   (done)
o o 2 1      (2, 1)   (done)
o * 1 *
* * o o
```

Continue this until we run out of neighbors:

```
  grid       two_do   one_do
3 o 1 o      (done)   (3, 1)
o o 2 1      (done)
o 2 1 2
* * o o

  grid       two_do   one_do
3 o 1 o      (3, 0)   (done)
o o 2 1
o 2 1 2
* 1 o o

  grid       two_do   one_do
3 o 1 o      (done)
o o 2 1
o 2 1 2
2 1 o o
```

You are now out of open `*`s in the grid, so you're done.

Comment: This is complicated. 3s are easy, and you can decide 1 vs 2 by the parity of the sum of the coordinates.

Comment: NO kidding.  That's why I up-voted the other answer.  :-)  This is good only if you have a requirement to maintain a certain parity with respect to a defined starting point of each region, independent of the others.

Answer (score 0):

You'll make a series of loops over the rectangle, as long as you "changed anything" the last time, loop again.  Once you scan the whole array and find nothing changed, you're done.

You'll want a set of coordinates to remember what's been processed, and a workQueue to remember what needs to be done.

Each loop iteration you'll find the first * just by scanning.  Once found, push it into workQueue with the following information (x,y,t), where x,y are the coordinates in the rectangle, and t is the target value 1 to set it to, and set "didSomething" to true.

1) remove the first element from the queue, set the x,y coordinate in your rectangle to whatever value its 't' field is.  Set some variable "DidSomething" to true.

2) for every neighbor of x,y that has a *, if those coordinates are not in the alreadyProcessed set, add them to the work queue, flipping the value t from 1->2 or 2->1, and add those coordinates to the alreadyProcessed queue.

3) if the queue is not empty, loop back to step 1

Eventually you'll cover all the neighboring cells and drain the queue.  This "fill" is complete, but since didSomething is true, you'll scan again looking for any remaining * characters.  If you find any, jump back to the fill routine.

Good luck, and post your code when you're done.  :)